# Export Excel table to MS Access table (without duplicating data on subsequent runs)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to transfer my Excel table directly to MS Access with VBA.

This solution
[Using Excel VBA to export data to MS Access table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161865/using-excel-vba-to-export-data-to-ms-access-table) only adds the range of data.

Is it possible to export Excel table to MS Access table directly?

Every time I run this code, it duplicates the data. I can't edit the sCommand into Update statement it gives me an error.

```vb
Sub test()
dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
dsh = "[" & Application.ActiveSheet.Name & "$]" & "Data2"  'Data2 is a named range

sdbpath = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Database2.mdb"
sCommand = "INSERT INTO [main] ([dte], [test1], [values], [values2]) SELECT [haha],[test1],[values],[values2] FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh

Dim dbCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim dbCommand As New ADODB.Command

dbCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sdbpath & "; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;"
dbCommand.ActiveConnection = dbCon

dbCommand.CommandText = sCommand
dbCommand.Execute

dbCon.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add the code you did try.

Comment: In Access, try linking to the table by getting external data. It will launch a wizard dialog to walk you through. No VBA needed.

Comment: @bugdrown The data I needed to be ms access table is being encoded only using excel. So I need to convert it every time to ms access. I need the ms access table format to load it in vb.net application.

Comment: What if you ran a `DELETE` query on the target table before you run `dbCommand.Execute`?