# Excel VBA export content part of pivot table to database / csv file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I wish to export the data region of the pivot table into a database (MS access / Oracle) or alternatively save it as a CSV file. I do not know how to define the dynamic region for selection of the data region.

The filtered pivot table looks like

[image]

and I wish to export the region

[image]

i.e the content part of pivot table into DB (or simply even as CSV file)

I do not how to select the relevant portion to export as numbers of will change on refresh or filter changes.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161865/using-excel-vba-to-export-data-to-ms-access-table